# tensorflow-model-server for centos rhel 7 without docker

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Is there any way to user tensorflow-model-server for centos rhel 7 without docker.
I am not able to find documentation for it

Answer (score 0):

Build binary from source code.

Comment: Can you please share the steps for building the binary without using docker

Comment: Just follow official dockerfile, to check which packages are needed. Then install them on you centos server. For example, official docker installed ca-certificates by `apt-get  install -y ca-certificates`, you should install it by `yum install -y ca-certificates`